# Wake up an iOS app from background with a notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, webrtc, firebase-notifications

I have an iOS app with Firebase Cloud Messaging to manage my push notifications. It works well, but I'd like to open my app (while in background state) when I receive my push notification. A bit like WhatsApp, with a custom calling (WebRTC) view.

Any ideas?

Apparently I should use PushKit to do what I want to do.

Is there an other way to do that ... like `Signal` application. A ringing notification (push ?), and then user click on to open app.

Comment: You need to implement Apple pushKit instead of APNS.

Comment: Thanks. How could I implement PushKit ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit

Comment: Ok thanks. I haven't any idea how to implement that. Do you have some pretty good articles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till FCM does not support silent push notification ( Push kit ).

Using Pushkit is only current technique to send silent push notification to device.

One you receive silent push notification payload, then you have to schedule local notification because silent push notification does not come in notification center. upto your local notification sound file plays ( Max 30 seconds ) your application will be invoke in background or kill state. you can do require activity here but not UI activity.

While tapping on interactive local notification you can do further UI activity.

Use below structure to achieve your task.

Use this simplepush.php file

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):

    
      $deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//

    
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
                     'content-available'=> 1,
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default',
                     'badge' => 0,
                     );

    

// Encode the payload as JSON
    
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Use below commands to create pem file and use it in above code

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushCert.pem

# Convert .p12 to .pem. Enter your pass pharse which is the same pwd that you have given while creating the .p12 certificate. PEM pass phrase also same as .p12 cert.  
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey1.pem -in pushkey.p12

Enter Import Password:

MAC verified OK

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

# To remove passpharse for the key to access globally. This only solved my stream_socket_client() & certificate capath warnings.
$ openssl rsa -in PushKey1.pem -out PushKey1_Rmv.pem

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:

writing RSA key

# To join the two .pem file into one file:
$ cat PushCert.pem PushKey1_Rmv.pem > ApnsDev.pem
```

After that go to simplepush.php location and fire command -> php simplepush.php

This way you can test your push kit notification setup architecture.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

[Download](https://drive.google.com/a/brainvire.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaGxGZVV4X0Y0d3M/view)

```
import UIKit
import PushKit


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate{



func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)

    self. PushKitRegistration()

    return true
}



//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{

    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

        // Set the registry's delegate to self

        voipRegistry.delegate = self

        // Set the push type to VoIP

        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

    print(hexString)


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    // Process the received push
    // From here you have to schedule your local notification

}

}
```

[image]

[image]

In parallel if you setup Socket architecture. Then Socket used to broadcast data for example which users are online / offline and you need to know without calling an API then you can use socket, socket architecture on server will send data on online / offline user to devices without making request from device.

Comment: Hey, thanks. So I have to implement PushKit instead of push notifications. In the facts, that's exactly what I want for my app ... but I haven't any ideas how to implement that. I already read the Apple PushKit reference, but I'm a little bit lost. Could you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try your code soon, and come back to you if needed. Just another question ... must I create a Apple developer certificate to do that ?

Comment: Welcome, you can contact me anytime for VOIP related consulting.

Comment: Hey I've tried your code, but without any success. I haven't token printed to the console. Could you help me ? Maybe to generate the certificate and provisioning profile ?

Comment: Yes, if you are not getting token. then there must be some issue with certificate. can you please verify with this https://zeropush.com/guide/guide-to-pushkit-and-voip

Comment: I have just tried with code which i have with certificates i made for pushkit, i am able to get token and notification too. i doubt on your certificates, you have figure out some way, check this also https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial , i hope you are running app on device as simulator would not give token.

Comment: Must I create a development or production certificate ? With Push notification (dev, dist, or both ?) ? ...

Comment: Pushkit works with development also. no need for distribution or production.

Comment: I just downloaded your project, generated my voip certificate, and then run the app, but there is nothing to show in the console. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I hope you are running app on device, Simulator would not give token. if still from my code and certificate which you configured and you are not getting token, then i am sure something is still wrong with certificates.

Comment: Hey, I think I had a problem with my certificate ... now when I compile (yes on my device), I get the token :) ... I'll try next steps. Thx ;)

Comment: Could you explain to me the steps to generate the correct pem ? I'm a little bit confused with that ... Thanks.

Comment: Hope this helps to understand steps to create pem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175570/push-notification-error-unable-to-set-local-cert-chain-file

Comment: Thanks. I used my aps_development.cer with the associate Certificate.p12 to generate the pem. I copy your php, and just changed the token ... but when I execute, I get some errors like : "SSL operation failed", "Failed to enable crypto" or "unable to connect to ssl://....". Let me know if I'm good with my pem generation or it's something else ?! Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125716/discussion-between-parnissolle-and-hasya).